# JAVA implementation of PIL image resize with Image.NEAREST resampling option

Tags: java, python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I need to convert my python image resize logic to java and I am wondering what would be the correct java implementation for resizing image with image.NEAREST resampling argument.

python code:

```
from PIL import Image
image.resize((299,299),Image.NEAREST)
```

For Java implementation, I am using this:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
    
BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(),bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 

Image img = bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(bufferedImage.getWidth(),bufferedImage.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

Based on the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Image.html, SCALED_SMOOTH means:  Choose an image-scaling algorithm that gives higher priority to image smoothness than scaling speed. I cannot find what the algorithm is behind the Java implementation.

There is a difference between the results of python and Java implementations.
Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: I think you can use `new AffineTransformOp(transform, TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR).filter(bufferedImage, scaledImage)`. Or `BufferedImage scaledImage = new AffineTransformOp(transform, TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR).filter(bufferedImage, null)` if you like the scale filter to compute the destination iamge/size for you.

Comment: You could probably also use the `Image.getScaledInstance(..., SCALE_REPLICATE)`, but I *really don't recommend using this API*, as it's asynchronous-behind-the-scenes behavior is often confusing.

Comment: Sure - let me try and I will get back to you